# "Set-Cookie" header does not set cookie

Tags: java, spring-boot, cookies

I'm developing a Spring Boot app (backend) with Vaadin (frontend). The app is secured with HTTPS and uses JWT in authentication & authorization process.

I've got a simple `/login` view where there are two `TextField` fields for username and password. Clicking `Login` button sends an HTTPS request using `WebClient` class. The client receives JWT value in a successful response which also contains `Set-Cookie` header that looks like this: `token=SOME_JWT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly`. Now, the issue is that this header does not actually set any cookie. I use Firefox and there's nothing in cookie storage.

Here's how the view class looks like (it includes the WebClient config).

```
@PageTitle("Login")
@Route(value = "login")
public class LogView extends VerticalLayout {

    private WebClient webClient;

    public LogView(WebClient.Builder builder) throws IOException {
        this.webClient = webClient(builder);

        TextField username = new TextField("Username");
        TextField password = new TextField("Password");
        add(username, password);

        add(new Button("Login", (click) -> {
            String jsonBody = "{\n"
                    + "  \"username\": \"" + username.getValue() + "\",\n"
                    + "  \"password\": \"" + password.getValue() + "\"\n"
                    + "}";
            var response = this.webClient
                    .post()
                    .uri("/api/auth/authenticate")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(jsonBody))
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(AuthResponseDTO.class);
        }));
    }
    
    private WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) throws SSLException {
        SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                .forClient()
                .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                .build();
        ClientHttpConnector httpConnector =  new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslContext)));

        this.webClient = webClientBuilder
                .clientConnector(httpConnector)
                .baseUrl("https://127.0.0.1:8433")
                .build();
        return webClient;
    }
}
```

And here's also an authentication endpoint from `AuthController`:

```
    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public AuthResponseDTO authenticate(@RequestBody AuthRequestDTO request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        AuthResponseDTO tokenDTO = authService.authenticate(request);
        this.addAuthCookie(response, tokenDTO);
        return tokenDTO;
    }

    private void addAuthCookie(HttpServletResponse response, AuthResponseDTO tokenDTO) {
        response.addCookie(createAuthCookie(tokenDTO.getToken()));
    }

    private Cookie createAuthCookie(String token) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token", token);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setSecure(true);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        return cookie;
    }
```